# How to use an object as model-attribute in Ember.js and Ember data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm developing a flashcard app that shows the chinese characters to the user.
I have a App.User class setup with all of the properties, however I have great difficulty keeping track with the trial-property, which keeps track of the number fo times the user has been exposed to that particular character/sinogram.

The application controller is supposed to store the current logged in user and it's details as attributes. But I can't seem to get hold of the object in the trials attribute or how to do that in ember and ember data. I read something about extending the supported attribute types, but I honestly have no idea how to make it work. (http://www.kaspertidemann.com/representing-objects-in-ember-data)
Eventually a REST-api php-backend is gonna provide the data, but for now I'm using ember data's fixtures.adapter to test it in my app.
Any help on this is greatly appreciated! Thanx in advance.

PS: I tried to be as complete as possible, but if anything is unclear just let me know and I'll provide more details!

```
// This template has a button which trigger the login action
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
    <div class="content">
        <form class="input-group">
            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Username</label>
                {{input type="text" value=username placeholder='username'}}
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Password</label>
                {{input type="password"  value=password placeholder='password'}}
            </div>
            <button {{action 'login'}} class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outlined">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</script>

// application controller
    App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    username: 'Sunchild',
    currentUser: {},
    // get the user.model
    particularUser: function() {
        return this.get('userArray').filterBy('username', this.get('username'));
        }.property('userArray.@each.username'),
    login: function(){
        if ((this.get('particularUser').getEach('hed_password') == _password)){
        // Code to store all the App.user info on the controller.
        // I figured I just set the currentUser property to the object, 
        // but I don't know how to get to the currentUser.trials property.
        this.set('currentUser', this.get('particularUser'));
        var _trialsObject = this.get('currentUser').getEach('trials');
        for (var key in _trialsObject) {
            // Does not work
        }
    }
});

// Router and Routes
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('signup');
    this.resource('login');
    this.resource('profile');
    this.resource('practice');
    this.resource('overview');
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});

// The trials property is an object which should keep count of the number fo times the user has seen the flashcard with this character/sinogram
(function () {
    'use strict';

    App.User = DS.Model.extend({
        id: DS.attr('number'),
        username: DS.attr('string'),
        firstname: DS.attr('string'),
        lastname: DS.attr('string'),
        email: DS.attr('string'),
        hed_password: DS.attr(),
        trials: DS.attr(),
    });
})();

App.User.FIXTURES = [
 {
    id: 1,
    username: 'LargeSushi',
    firstname: 'Secil',
    lastname: 'Calzone',
    email: 'Secil@gmail.com',
    hed_password: 5432,
    trials: {"U+73ED": 1, "U+554A": 1}
    },
 {
    id: 2,
    username: 'Sunchild',
    firstname: 'Xiao',
    lastname: 'Feng',
    email: 'Sunchild@gmail.com',
    hed_password: 8754,
    trials: {"U+73ED": 1, "U+554A": 1}
 }
];
```